# using Getinstance method (singleton) on the same class

Tags: c#, timer, singleton

my friend and I are creating a program in C# for a college project.
We are trying to use the singleton technique in a class called Manager, and then use the GetInstance() in **the same class** (Manager) in a function that's called every T (interval) by a Timer.

What we get is an un-ordered flow of actions, meaning that in the debugger we can clearly see that there is no definite "flow" (we suspect we are accidently prompting a recursive function.)

We are also quite unsure if we are using the Timer correctly.
DateQueue is just the name we used for the Queue in our project. It functions completely like a Queue (implemented by a double-linkedlist)

```
    private static Manager _instance;
    public static Manager GetInstance()
    {
        if (_instance == null)
            _instance = new Manager();
        return _instance;
    }
    public Manager()
    {
        DocumentHash = new Dictionary<string, Doc>();
        deleteTimer = new Timer(DeleteOld, null, 0, 1000);
    }


 private static void DeleteOld(object o)
    {
        DateQueue<TimeData> tempQueue = DateQueue<TimeData>.GetInstance();
        Manager tempManager = Manager.GetInstance();
        TimeSpan deleteEveryTS = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10);
        DateTime dateForDelete = new DateTime();
        dateForDelete = DateTime.Now;
        dateForDelete -= deleteEveryTS;
        TimeData temp = default(TimeData);
```

**NOTICE** we didn't add the entire function simply because Visual Studio never reaches beyond this point and the rest is irrelevant to this problem., so there was no point uploading it.

We also have a problem that the DeleteOld has to be static because it's being called by the Timer (System.Threading), but we need this function to use non-static fields and methods in the lines that we didn't upload.

Comment: There are multiple `Timer`'s, can you tell us the exact namespace you are getting that Timer from?

Comment: Ideally provide a [mcve], as it's very hard to tell what's going on from just the code you've shown here. There's no indication of recursion here, but we have no idea what `DateQueue` etc are.

Comment: We are using the System.Threading namespace.

Comment: What's the issue with this code? Static methods can not use non-static members of the class. That behavior can not be changed. There is no solution for that.

Comment: Can we use the singleton on the same class?
meaning: class Manager has the GetInstance() method, and we are trying to use this GetInstance INSIDE the class in one of its functions.